# Reach through several relationships to get model from ember-data

Tags: ember-data

I am setting the contents of one menu based on the selected value of another one. The first menu is a set of companies. A Company has an OrderProfile; an OrderProfile has a Warehouse. So based on a known Company, I need to reach through the OrderProfile and get a Warehouse.

Here's what happens in the console when I have the Company in a `company` variable:

```
company.get('orderProfile.warehouse.name') # Ember-data gets the OrderProfile but not the Warehouse
// => null
var op = company.get('orderProfile')
// => undefined # The OrderProfile assigned to the variable
var warehouse = op.get('warehouse')
// undefined # Now the Warehouse is assigned to the variable
warehouse.get('name')
// => "Warehouse 1" # This was null when we asked for company.orderProfile.warehouse.name
```

So I know I need to unravel this in several steps, waiting for each to complete. Is there an Ember idiom for doing this?

N.B. this is using:

```
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.0-beta.1+canary.13995621 index.js:3496
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary index.js:3496
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how we worked this out. As I suspected, the key was handling the promises correctly, but we also had to be sure we had `async: true` set on the relevant relationships.

```coffeescript
warehouse = company.get("orderProfile.warehouse.name") # Doesn't work

# Instead, we need to treat orderProfile as a promise, and ask for the warehouse
# once it resolves:
company.get("orderProfile").then(
  (orderProfile) ->
    return orderProfile.get("warehouse") if orderProfile
).then(
  (warehouse) =>
    # Do something with the warehouse
)
```

As I understand it, the relationships - specifically `orderProfile: DS.belongsTo 'orderProfile', async: true` in the Company model - need `async: true` to remind Ember-Data that it might not already have the referenced models, and it needs to fetch them. I was on the right track figuring out the promise handling, but the `async: true` part was the real key.